# Changing font depending on data in table

Tags: vb.net

I have a table which stores the terms and conditions of a contract.
The fields are:

```
tandc      Text
bold       Text
italic     Text
underline  Text
```

Sample data:

```
Delivery within 6 months        yes    no    yes
Full payment within 3 months    yes    no    no
```

When I retrieve the data I need it to be displayed in such a way that if the value in the field named `bold` is `yes` then the data should be `bold`.  If `bold` and `italic` are `yes` then data should be `bold` and `italic` and so on.

How do I do this.

I am using vb.net, ms access and the data is to be displayed in a richtextbox.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how you can programmatically change the richtextbox to bold. Your question however is not very clear in regards to the data aspect. Please show your code if you need more help.

```
 With Me.RichTextBox1
        If .SelectionFont IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim currentFont As System.Drawing.Font = .SelectionFont
            Dim newFontStyle As System.Drawing.FontStyle

            If .SelectionFont.Bold = True Then
                newFontStyle = currentFont.Style - Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
            Else
                newFontStyle = currentFont.Style + Drawing.FontStyle.Bold
            End If

            .SelectionFont = New Drawing.Font(currentFont.FontFamily, currentFont.Size, newFontStyle)
        End If
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response.

Comment: My table has 4 fields namely tandc, bold, italic, underline.   I will give an example of the data:  'Payment must be done within 6 months (this is in the tandc field), 'yes' (bold), 'no' (italic), 'yes' (underline).  Since the value in the bold and underline fields are 'yes' I need to display the data in the tandc field (Payment must be done within 6 months) as bold and underlined.  Similarly for other rows of data also.

Comment: If bld = "yes" And itl = "yes" And und = "yes" Then
                        fnt = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic Or FontStyle.Underline)

                        rtb.SelectionFont = fnt

                        rtb.Text = rtb.Text & txt & vbNewLine
                    ElseIf bld = "yes" And itl = "yes" And und = "no" Then
                        fnt = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25, FontStyle.Bold Or FontStyle.Italic)

                        rtb.SelectionFont = fnt

                        rtb.Text = rtb.Text & txt & vbNewLine